# Member function not work in cons structure

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I write two program one is to takeoutAllButLast , other is  takeoutSecondLast.

I initially use the member function to determine whether there is more X behind.

And I try some data and find that:

If the first argument is a symbol, they both work!

But if it is cons structure, they both fail.

```
1.// `(a b)   `((b b)(a b)(b c)(a b)) ==>  `((b b)(b c)(a b)) 

(defun takeoutAllButLast (X L)
(cond ((null L) nil)
       ((equal X (first L)) 
           (if (member X (rest L)) 
               (takeoutAllButLast X (rest L)) 
               L)) 
       (t (cons (first L) (takeoutAllButLast X (rest L))))
)
)

2.//`(a b)   `((a b)(b b)(a b)(b c)(a b)) ==>  `((a b)(b b)(b c)(a b)) 
(defun takeoutSecondLast (X L)
(cond ((null L) nil)
       ((equal X (first L)) 
           (if (member X (rest (member X (rest L))))
    (cons (first L) (takeoutSecondLast X (rest L)))
    (rest L)
           )
    )
   (t (cons (first L) (takeoutSecondLast X (rest L))))
 )
```

What I want to ask is how to determine whether there is still one element is X behind, and can be used like member function?

And why member function cannot be used to compare cons structure?

Thx for you reading my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member` defaults to using `eql` as its equality predicate. That works fine on symbols, numbers and a few other things (that is `(eq 'a 'a)` is always true, `(let ((cons (cons 'a 'a))) (eql cons cons))` is always true, but `(eql (cons 'a 'a) (cons 'a 'a))` is almost never true).

You can pass an alternative equality checker to `member` using the `:test` keyword and if you use `#'equal` you will (probably) get what you want.

If you want to call `member` with the custom equality checker `foo`, simply do:

```
(member thing-to-check-for the-list-to-check :test #'foo)
```

Comment: Can you give a example to pass an equality checker to member? Thank you.

Comment: Try (member X (rest L) :test #'equal)